# activescaffold @records manipulation in a before filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, activescaffold

I would like to call

```
@records.collect{|r| r.set_some_virtual_attribute(@context)}
```

before rendering an activescaffold index view, but if I do this :

```
controller FooController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :change_things, :only => :index
  active_scaffold :foos

  protected

  def change_things
     @records.collect{|r| r.set_some_virtual_attribute(@context)}
  end
end
```

I get :

```
 You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
 You might have expected an instance of Array. 
 The error occurred while evaluating nil.collect
```

when calling the index view. The same thing happens if I put the filter after the ActiveScaffold call.  I would be fine with taking a different approach of some sort, but the bottom line is that I need to set a virtual attribute of each object in @records based on some context from the controller for display in the final table

thx

-C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't really need to access this collection in the controller. what i wanted to do can be solved with the appropriate helper methods being defined.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't testing this but i think it should be @foos.collect rather than @records.collect